# Why when i refresh my list it duplicates?

Tags: android, listview, fragment, refresh

this is my problem: 
First i have a listview like this:

[image: image1]

When I click on first row (for expemple prod3) appears my dialog like this (this is for delete clicked row):

[image: image2]

But when i refresh my fragment happens this thing:

[image: image3]

Why? there is a function like "revalidate, repaint" (java) on Android ?

This is my code when i click on row:

```
  public void mostraProdotto(String tito){

    final  EditText textprod;
    final  EditText prezzo;

    Button btnConf;
    Button btnDelete;
    final Dialog dialogCustom = new Dialog(getActivity());

    dialogBuilder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    //process

    dialogCustom.setContentView(R.layout.spesa_pagata);
    dialogCustom.setTitle("Nome Prod");
    textprod = (EditText)dialogCustom.findViewById(R.id.textprod);
    textprod.setText(tito);
    prezzo = (EditText)dialogCustom.findViewById(R.id.txtprezzo);
    btnConf = (Button)dialogCustom.findViewById(R.id.btnConf);


    btnConf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String nomeprod = textprod.getText().toString();
            String strprezzo = prezzo.getText().toString();

            if(!nomeprod.isEmpty() && !strprezzo.isEmpty()) {

       ..............


               new getSpesa().execute(); //getSpesa is for see listview
                dialogCustom.cancel();



        }

        }
    });
```

and this is code to fill list:

```
                    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_spesa);
                    listView.setY(20);
                    adapter = new CustomListAdapterSpesa(getActivity(), movieList);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

EDIT:

this is my customadapter

```
public class CustomListAdapterSpesa extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<MovieSpesa> movieItems;

int pos;
public CustomListAdapterSpesa(Activity activity, List<MovieSpesa> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);


    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

      TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
  convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    MovieSpesa m = movieItems.get(position);


    int coint = getCount();


    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());



    // genre


    genre.setText(m.getGenre());

    return convertView;

}
```

}

Comment: Please add the custom adapter

Comment: Probably items added in `movieList` when refreshing ListView. simply clear `movieList` before adding items on refersh

Comment: And also how you initialize the movieList in the code

Comment: How you fill your moveList ? I think you are adding objects into the list

Comment: It's true @FarshidABZ i think i only adding object, how can i clear movielist?

Comment: moveList.clear() , or use local object instead of global @francescobocci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adapter is written correctly, so the problem might be on list side.

You posted this code:

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_spesa);
listView.setY(20);
adapter = new CustomListAdapterSpesa(getActivity(), movieList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem must be on how `movieList` is used, it must has a *class-scope* and **not a local scope**.

So you have two possible solutions:

1. Use `movieList.clear();` before adding the other `items`. This method clears all items previouvsly added. In this way the only items inside the list will be the newly inserted ones.
2. You can Simply istantiate the `list` before the usage. (this means **locally**) In this way every time you call the method filling the `list`, the object itself will be re-created.

Hope this helps.